# Expo: MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync is creating multiple album with same name

Tags: expo, media-library

my function:

```
async function takePhotoNStore(){
    if(cameraRef){
        let picture = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync();
        const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(picture.uri);
        await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('Expo', asset, false);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create one album named "Expo" but it keeps creating multiple "Expo" album every time I take a new picture.

Comment: any work around?, Im facing same problem.

Comment: @MikeVictoria you can check my answer below if you still need it :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the album already exists with :

```
MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync(albumName)
```

If this is the case, you can add your assets with :

```
MediaLibrary.addAssetsToAlbumAsync(assets, album, copyAssets)
```

If not, create it like you did.

You won't have any duplication! :)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference

```
_saveToCameraRollAsync = async () => {
    try {
        let result = await captureRef(this.pageView, {
            format: 'png',
            quality: 0.9
        });

       
        const cachedAsset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(result);
        // saved the asset uri

        const album = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync('GWA');
        // check if the album if exist if return null you need to create an album.
      
        if (album === null) {
            // insert an album name with image
            const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(result);
            MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('GWA', asset)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('Album created!');
                    Alert.alert('Image has been saved')
                    this.setState({ cameraRollUri: asset });
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    Alert.alert(`Opps there's something wrong`)
                    console.log('err', error);
                });
        } else {
            // if album exist asset added
            let assetAdded = await MediaLibrary.addAssetsToAlbumAsync(
                [cachedAsset],
                album,
                false
            );
            if (assetAdded === true) {
                this.getAssetFromAlbum(album);
            } else {
                console.log("ASSET ADD ERROR");
            }
        }

    }
    catch (snapshotError) {
        console.error(snapshotError);
    }
};

getAssetFromAlbum = async album => {
    //function
    const assetResult = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
        first: 1,
        album: album,
        sortBy: MediaLibrary.SortBy.creationTime,
    });
    const asset = await assetResult.assets[0];

    this.setState({ image_uri: asset.uri });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
saveFile = async (fileUri) => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    if (status === "granted") {
      const cachedAsset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(fileUri);
      
      const albumName = "xyz';
      const album = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync(albumName)
      
      if(album){
        await MediaLibrary.addAssetsToAlbumAsync([cachedAsset], album, false);
      }else{
        const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(fileUri);
        await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync(albumName, asset);
      }
    }
  };
```